# Is fractional part of $e^n$ dense in (0,1)?

Tags: real-analysis, fractional-part

Can fractional part of $e^n$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ dense in $(0,1)$?

Generally, for which kind of $\alpha > 0$, $\{\alpha^n\}$ dense in $(0,1)$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The density of the fractional part of $x^n$ in $(0,1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951880/the-density-of-the-fractional-part-of-xn-in-0-1)

Comment: well, it's duplicate, but how about the case of $e^n$.

Comment: Would you accept "nobody knows" as an answer?

Comment: lol, I've searched in arxiv and found nothing, seems nobody knows indeed.